# .pigbootup not found

Tags: command-line, java

I have a problem trying to get this command to run.

I've got all the files in the correct directories, and  i'm running the command from within the correct directory. I've downloaded and unpacked Pig,and copied the .jar folder into my Pig directory.

However, when I run the command:

```
jon@ubuntu:~/Pig$ java -Xmx512M -cp pig-0.12.1.jar org.apache.pig.Main -x local wordCount.pig
```

I have got long error message form which the important part is :

```
[main] INFO  org.apache.pig.impl.util.Utils - Default bootup file /home/jon/.pigbootup not found
```

Please can any point me in the direction of where this could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [Apache Pig Tutorial](http://www.rohitmenon.com/index.php/apache-pig-tutorial-part-1/).

Under "Installing Pig" have you added the following to your `.bashrc`?

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/hduser/pig/bin
```

If so, then simply running `pig` or `pig -x local` should work.

*NOTE: This tutorial assumes that Pig is running as "hduser" so if that is not the case for you, adjust accordingly.*

Both examples (of starting Pig from the tutorial) display your error message (mentioned above) and it appears to be merely informational, and should still drop you at the Pig Latin prompt.  If your system is behaving differently, please indicate so in the comments.

Comment: Many thanks @BryceAtNetwork23, worked for me on my set up.